# How to enable popup windows to appear in a certain location on a web page

Tags: jquery

Refer to the [economist](http://www.economist.com) site and popup windows appear at the bottom of the page to enable you to subscribe to the site. Similarly other sites have promotional items popup mostly from the bottom of the page at random times. What control should I use to enable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a jQuery UI Dialog with the position option set to the location where you want the dialog to be displayed. Check this URL: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-position